# Add a style to the Top Level element only

Tags: html, css

I have a drop-down menu (list) made up of `ul` and `li` elements.

Each `li` element has a nested `a` element.

Elements without children have a class of `leaf`.

Elements at the end of each list are given the class `last`.

(I did not write nor design this menu. This is a project I was assigned at work and the menu is being built by Drupal 7)

The only method I have of modifying these menu items is through CSS.

I would like to modify the last two menu items in the **top level** of the list.

Both of these items have the class `leaf`, and the last one also has the class `last`.

Here is what I did:

```
.desktop.navigation .leaf {
       padding-left:10px;
       padding-right: 10px;
       margin-right: 5px !important;
       background-color: rgb(55, 166, 97);
}

.desktop.navigation .leaf > a{
       color: white;
       font-weight: bold;
}

.desktop.navigation .last {
       padding-left:10px;
       padding-right: 10px;
       margin-left: 5px !important;
       background-color: rgb(55, 97, 166);
}

.desktop.navigation .last > a{
       color: white;
       font-weight: bold;
}
```

This CSS does what I want to the top level nodes, yet it also affects the nodes at lower levels as well.

Is there any way that I can **only apply these styles to the top level nodes of my menu?**

The only way that I can think of to isolate these `li` elements is the fact that their `ul` parent does not have a `ul` parent. The other `li` elements being affected (the ones that I do not want to be affected) have a parent `ul` element, yet that parent `ul` element has a parent `ul` element.

And as requested by @emmanuel; an image of my html (since Drupal wrote all the HTML and I can't modify it, otherwise I wouldn't have this problem):

[image: List]

Comment: Please create a code snippet including your html code.

Comment: Well, I can steal it from the Javascript console I guess. Ok, hold on...

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding CSS for lower level menu items as well, that will clear the changes you made to the top level. For example:

```
.desktop.navigation .leaf li {
    /* css for lower level li */
}
.desktop.navigation .leaf li a {
    /* css for lower level a
}
```

Try something like this:

```
ul.menu li a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.menu li ul li a {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: I see what your saying, yet I would have to make a specific CSS statement for each lower level item, and this list changes dynamically...

Comment: I don't know what HTML looks like, but if you need one style for top level and different style for all other menu items, then this should do the trick, since additional css will affect everything below `.leaf li`.

Answer (score 0):

This could help.

```
*:not(li) > ul > li > a {} /* for top level list items */
*:not(li) > ul > li.leaf >a {} /* for top level Leaf items */
```

The second way, or for better understanding, first look for the parent node of the top level `ul`, such as `div.navigation`, then use

```
div.navigation > ul > li > a {}
div.navigation > ul > li.leaf > a {}
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MenuSo/jp5L4ehk/3/

Answer (score 0):

All of you posted very good answers, and through your answers I have learned a lot about CSS, yet I appear to have solved my own question.

Unfortunatley, I was unable to target the exact elements I wanted with one statement. I had to target every last child of every menu, then follow that statement with a cancelling statement for lower level children.

```
ul.menu > li.leaf {
       padding-left:10px;
       padding-right: 10px;
       margin-right: 5px !important;
       background-color: rgb(55, 166, 97);
}

/*
Cancel
*/
ul.menu > li.expanded > ul.menu > li.leaf {
       padding-left: 10px !important;
       padding-right: 10px !important;
       margin-right: 0px !important;
}

ul.menu > li.last {
       padding-left:10px;
       padding-right: 10px;
       margin-left: 5px !important;
       background-color: rgb(55, 97, 166);
}

/*
Cancel
*/
ul.menu > li.expanded > ul.menu > li.last {
       padding-left: 10px !important;
       padding-right: 10px !important;
       margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```